# Delayed slow-down effect on Full-Screen programs

Tags: windows-7, performance, virus

Well, **after about 2-3 minutes after starting a Full-Screen program, it slows down a lot, becoming extremely laggy.** *My computer used to be top-performant previously.*
I scanned my Computer with an older Antivirus (AVG 2013). It found some threats, but it didn't seem to improve this. I also tried AVG Tune-up to repair any possible errors related to this, but *it still didn't work.*
**So, what should I do? Is it a known issue?**
Additional information: I am running Windows 7, and the issue happens with most of my programs, when in Full-Screen.

Comment: A little more information could help clear this up. What operating system are you running? Does this happen with any program, or just a specific one? Are you sure that it only happens when it's full-screen? Also, try opening task manager/system monitor/whatever-your-OS-uses and looking for changes in the data(specifically, ram and cpu usage) when your computer starts to slow down.

Comment: See the Tags (Windows 7), and it happens with most Full-Screen programs. There are some exceptions, however. @AntonLiakhovitch